# Specifying the host element type on an Angular Directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am building a directive in Angular (2+) and I want to limit the directive to which type of element it can be applied to.

Is there a built in Angular mechanism to specify that my directive can only be applied to an `<input />` tag? Or will I have to specifically check the element reference?

Comment: You can restrict the selector of your directive to `selector: 'input[myDirective]'`

Comment: @Jota.Toledo This worked, thanks for the help. Put it in an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: done, glad to hear it solved your issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you can archive this by using a restrictive `selector` in the metadata of the directive:

```
@Directive({
   ...
   selector: 'input[fooDirective]',
   exportAs: 'fooDir'
   ...
})
export class FooDirective {
}
```